# How to read Excel file that is protected view in C# using Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, selenium

I am using `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` to open the excel file and read through it. However, I can't get the cell D4's value from it. The `rangeObject` is becoming `null` Any ideas?

Here is the excel sheet I am using:

[image]

I need to get the value of Cell D4, which is 9.

```
public static string GetAmountFromReport()
    {
        var fileName = string.Empty;
        var downloadedFilesPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
            @"TestAutomationFramework\Utilities\DownloadedFiles");
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(downloadedFilesPath);
        var files = directoryInfo.GetFiles("report_export_*.xlsx");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        fileName = files[0].Name;
        var fullPathToFile = downloadedFilesPath + "\\" + fileName;

        var xls = new Excel.Application();
        var workBooks = xls.Workbooks;
        var workBook = workBooks.Open(fullPathToFile, ReadOnly: false, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended: true);
        var sheets = workBook.Worksheets;
        var workSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets[1];
        var rangeObject = workSheet1.Cells[4, "D"] as Excel.Range;
        var amountFromCell = rangeObject.Value.ToString();

        // removing from Memory
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
        workBook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBooks);

        xls.Application.Quit(); // THIS IS WHAT IS CAUSES EXCEL TO CLOSE
        xls.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xls);

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
        return amountFromCell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest skipping the Interop and using the nuget package: [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/). It does not require excel on the running machine and also works in Linux builds of Core applications.

The library does support password protected excel files.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much that you can collect from Excel workbook using interop APIs, but what you can collect is file name etc. Check out the sample code below.

```
var xls = new Excel.Application();
var activeProtectedViewWindow =
      xls?.ActiveProtectedViewWindow;
var spath =  activeProtectedViewWindow.SourcePath;
var sfname = activeProtectedViewWindow.SourceName;
```